# Problems installing node with nvim

Tags: installation, terminal, ubuntu-20.04, neovim

I got this message whe i try to use nvmi to install some version of node
I stricted follow the instructions in the page doesn't work.

```
    Downloading and installing node v14.17.6...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6-linux-x64.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file                                             
Warning: /home/facundo/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.17.6-linux-x64/node-v14.17.6-li
Warning: nux-x64.tar.xz: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/facundo/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v14.17.6-linux-x64/node-v14.17.6-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
Detected that you have 8 CPU core(s)
Running with 7 threads to speed up the build
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6.tar.xz...
Warning: Failed to create the file                                             
Warning: /home/facundo/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6.tar.xz: 
Warning: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination

Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/facundo/.nvm/.cache/src/node-v14.17.6/node-v14.17.6.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the commands and which documentation you're following. The `NVM` installation is quite straightforward.

(1/4) `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash` make sure you've curl installed. `curl --version` gave me `7.68.0`

(2/4) `export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm`

(3/4) `source ~/.bashrc` to get the nvm command in terminal

You're now ready for `nvm` command.

(4/4) `nvm ls-remote` for checking the available versions, now you can select the explicitly which version you're to install or you can install the latest `lts` version with `nvm install 'lts/*'`

Source : [Github Official NVM docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Comment: I've already nvm installed.
The message is when i try to use it to install node.
`nvm install v14.16.1`
And get the error in the post.

When i use the export command of your second step i get

`bash: export: `[': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `-s': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/home/facundo/.nvm/nvm.sh': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `]': not a valid identifier
`

Comment: Did you installed nvm as sudo, and now trying to install as non-sudo ? I think you need to go superuser to install `node` with nvm command.